# What's the purpose of "was" in "Hast du schon was vor?"?

Tags: word-usage

**Hast du schon was vor?**
Duo said this is translated as "Do you have plans yet?" But I'm not sure what "was" adds to it?  "Do you have something planned?"  Is that it?  I've seen it in another sentence too.  **Hast du noch was Geld** "Do you still have something money?"  but "was" is a shortened form of etwas meaning "something".  Help me bitte!  And please help me understand the reasoning for using "was".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Hast du schon **(et)was** vor?

The relevant verb phrase is *etwas vorhaben — to have something on, to be up to something*. So it means

- *Are you up to something yet?*

That “something” *etwas* may be shortened to *was* in colloquial German.

---

> Hast du noch **etwas** Geld?

This one is entirely different. You can't shorten the *etwas* to *was* in this phrase as this *etwas* doesn't mean *something* but *some*. It would be wrong even in colloquial German. So it means

- Do you still have some money?

Comment: I suggest to add the conclusion to the second part that *Hast du noch was Geld* is colloquial at best (if not outright wrong) and can't be recommended for use.

Comment: It would be nice to mention that shortening "etwas" to "was" is somewhat colloquial and likely most used in spoken, not written language. (And "Hast du noch was Geld" is entirely colloquial - I actually do hear that frequently.)

Comment: Thank you!  You guys are amazing!  I love this platform and I got help so quick!.  And such great answers!!  Thanks  